# data normalization after prediction RF

Tags: machine-learning, normalization, random-forest, prediction

using RandomForest  algorithm to regression i found in iternet than after predicting they normalize the predicted results that means we suppose that the result is pred

pred = pred = pred*(np.exp(-pred/100)*2+1)

do you have any idea why normalize the results of prediction and why this formula and which kind of normalization of the predicted results can be done ?

Answer (score 1):

In short: **dont do such a random thing**.

More detailed answer:
There is no reason for doing any kind of "fixed equation" postprocessing. The only reason to apply f(x) to your predictions is **if you applied f^-1(x) before training**. In other words - if you somehow transformed your data prior to training you need to apply inverse transformation to the prediction to get back to the original space.

Just to show how useless is the equation provided, consider regression problem with negative outputs, for example befween -10000 and 0. Lets say that your model is not perfect and predicts -9900 instead of -10000, according to this "rule" you get (-9900)*(np.exp(-(-9900)/100)*2+1) which is something among the lines of -200,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000 (-2e47).

Comment: sorry i did not understand your answer very well but if we suppose the result is -9900 the result will not be -2e47 because we multiply by exp (-predicted) and not  exp (--predicted) i test it and the result with  this formula is better i don't know really why

Comment: you are using exp(-predicted), predicted is -9900 so you get exp(9900), this is how math works, if you placed "-" by mistake in your example, then just change my counterexample to predicting 9900 and the same thing happens.